# How to use jQuery to download zip file which directly ouput from server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php script that will generate zip file.

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=random_name.zip");
echo $zipfile->file();
```

The filename is random and the server script doesn't even come with a return-file-uri function.

So my question is that how jQuery can handle this output (echo $zipfile->file()) so that I can download the zip file in the usual way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Jesse

Comment: By download, you are thinking of the usual meaning of "download", right? Since I'm not sure what you mean by "jQuery handling this output". I'd say just `document.location.href = url` would be enough...

Comment: @Amadan - -1, not enough jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't handle downloads. Just point the browser to it directly.

Comment: thanks! I think it is almost a flight of fancy. lol I will look for another zip class to replace this one.